# Does LCD/LED display update when inactive/frozen?

Tags: display

When an LCD/LED display is inactive (showing the same static image, like a fullscreen photo), does the raster/VSync continue at — for example — 60Hz, displaying the same pixels? Or does it only update when something is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it does.

Regular LCD/LED displays always cycle when power is on regardless of an image being displayed or changing.